# Fckeditor content load incorrectly after page refresh

Tags: fckeditor

I'm sorry if my question have been asked already, but I didn't find the answer.

I have empty fckeditor. When I refresh the page, the content of this **fckeditor** was transferred to: `<p>&#160;</p>`

Actually, this content come from the **fckeditor** source mode.
Anyone know this problem.

Thanks for any reply!
Regards,
Tien